How to Parse Incoming Messages on the TON Blockchain?
I'm developing with the TON (Telegram Open Network) blockchain and facing challenges in parsing incoming messages. I aim to extract essential data such as sender information, the transaction amount, and the payload from these messages.
I'm open to using any programming language that is effective for this purpose, and I would appreciate guidance on the following points:

What programming languages and libraries are recommended for parsing incoming messages on the TON blockchain? If there are specific languages or tools that are particularly suited to this task, please advise.

How can I decode and interpret the data structure of these messages? TON uses the BOC (Bag of Cells) format for encoding messages, and I need advice on how to handle this format effectively.

Are there any sample code snippets, tutorials, or documentation available that demonstrate how to parse these messages? Practical examples or any educational resources would be extremely helpful to get started.


Any help or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated as I navigate through TON blockchain development!
My smart contract is written in TACT. I want to parse it using TON Console API in ts file

Have a look at this https://docs.ton.org/develop/dapps/cookbook. Scroll down until you find "How to parse transactions of an account (Transfers, Jettons, NFTs)?". Here’s the code:
import { Address, TonClient, beginCell, fromNano } from '@ton/ton';

async function main() {
    const client = new TonClient({
        endpoint: 'https://toncenter.com/api/v2/jsonRPC',
        apiKey: '1b312c91c3b691255130350a49ac5a0742454725f910756aff94dfe44858388e',
    });

    const myAddress = Address.parse('EQBKgXCNLPexWhs2L79kiARR1phGH1LwXxRbNsCFF9doc2lN'); // address that you want to fetch transactions from

    const transactions = await client.getTransactions(myAddress, {
        limit: 5,
    });

    for (const tx of transactions) {
        const inMsg = tx.inMessage;

        if (inMsg?.info.type == 'internal') {
            // we only process internal messages here because they are used the most
            // for external messages some of the fields are empty, but the main structure is similar
            const sender = inMsg?.info.src;
            const value = inMsg?.info.value.coins;

            const originalBody = inMsg?.body.beginParse();
            let body = originalBody.clone();
            if (body.remainingBits < 32) {
                // if body doesn't have opcode: it's a simple message without comment
                console.log(`Simple transfer from ${sender} with value ${fromNano(value)} TON`);
            } else {
                const op = body.loadUint(32);
                if (op == 0) {
                    // if opcode is 0: it's a simple message with comment
                    const comment = body.loadStringTail();
                    console.log(
                        `Simple transfer from ${sender} with value ${fromNano(value)} TON and comment: "${comment}"`
                    );
                } else if (op == 0x7362d09c) {
                    // if opcode is 0x7362d09c: it's a Jetton transfer notification

                    body.skip(64); // skip query_id
                    const jettonAmount = body.loadCoins();
                    const jettonSender = body.loadAddressAny();
                    const originalForwardPayload = body.loadBit() ? body.loadRef().beginParse() : body;
                    let forwardPayload = originalForwardPayload.clone();

                    // IMPORTANT: we have to verify the source of this message because it can be faked
                    const runStack = (await client.runMethod(sender, 'get_wallet_data')).stack;
                    runStack.skip(2);
                    const jettonMaster = runStack.readAddress();
                    const jettonWallet = (
                        await client.runMethod(jettonMaster, 'get_wallet_address', [
                            { type: 'slice', cell: beginCell().storeAddress(myAddress).endCell() },
                        ])
                    ).stack.readAddress();
                    if (!jettonWallet.equals(sender)) {
                        // if sender is not our real JettonWallet: this message was faked
                        console.log(`FAKE Jetton transfer`);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (forwardPayload.remainingBits < 32) {
                        // if forward payload doesn't have opcode: it's a simple Jetton transfer
                        console.log(`Jetton transfer from ${jettonSender} with value ${fromNano(jettonAmount)} Jetton`);
                    } else {
                        const forwardOp = forwardPayload.loadUint(32);
                        if (forwardOp == 0) {
                            // if forward payload opcode is 0: it's a simple Jetton transfer with comment
                            const comment = forwardPayload.loadStringTail();
                            console.log(
                                `Jetton transfer from ${jettonSender} with value ${fromNano(
                                    jettonAmount
                                )} Jetton and comment: "${comment}"`
                            );
                        } else {
                            // if forward payload opcode is something else: it's some message with arbitrary structure
                            // you may parse it manually if you know other opcodes or just print it as hex
                            console.log(
                                `Jetton transfer with unknown payload structure from ${jettonSender} with value ${fromNano(
                                    jettonAmount
                                )} Jetton and payload: ${originalForwardPayload}`
                            );
                        }

                        console.log(`Jetton Master: ${jettonMaster}`);
                    }
                } else if (op == 0x05138d91) {
                    // if opcode is 0x05138d91: it's a NFT transfer notification

                    body.skip(64); // skip query_id
                    const prevOwner = body.loadAddress();
                    const originalForwardPayload = body.loadBit() ? body.loadRef().beginParse() : body;
                    let forwardPayload = originalForwardPayload.clone();

                    // IMPORTANT: we have to verify the source of this message because it can be faked
                    const runStack = (await client.runMethod(sender, 'get_nft_data')).stack;
                    runStack.skip(1);
                    const index = runStack.readBigNumber();
                    const collection = runStack.readAddress();
                    const itemAddress = (
                        await client.runMethod(collection, 'get_nft_address_by_index', [{ type: 'int', value: index }])
                    ).stack.readAddress();

                    if (!itemAddress.equals(sender)) {
                        console.log(`FAKE NFT Transfer`);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (forwardPayload.remainingBits < 32) {
                        // if forward payload doesn't have opcode: it's a simple NFT transfer
                        console.log(`NFT transfer from ${prevOwner}`);
                    } else {
                        const forwardOp = forwardPayload.loadUint(32);
                        if (forwardOp == 0) {
                            // if forward payload opcode is 0: it's a simple NFT transfer with comment
                            const comment = forwardPayload.loadStringTail();
                            console.log(`NFT transfer from ${prevOwner} with comment: "${comment}"`);
                        } else {
                            // if forward payload opcode is something else: it's some message with arbitrary structure
                            // you may parse it manually if you know other opcodes or just print it as hex
                            console.log(
                                `NFT transfer with unknown payload structure from ${prevOwner} and payload: ${originalForwardPayload}`
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    console.log(`NFT Item: ${itemAddress}`);
                    console.log(`NFT Collection: ${collection}`);
                } else {
                    // if opcode is something else: it's some message with arbitrary structure
                    // you may parse it manually if you know other opcodes or just print it as hex
                    console.log(
                        `Message with unknown structure from ${sender} with value ${fromNano(
                            value
                        )} TON and body: ${originalBody}`
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(`Transaction Hash: ${tx.hash().toString('hex')}`);
        console.log(`Transaction LT: ${tx.lt}`);
        console.log();
    }
}

main().finally(() => console.log('Exiting...'));

